# Laravel 4 routing

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am new to Laravel 4 and am having a hard time grasping routes. I have a frontend to my site and a backend. All the stuff that happens on the backend I want to have displayed under `example.com/dashboard/...`. I also want to use resourceful controllers. What do I need to setup in `routes.php` to have it so I can always refer to my `users` controller but have it all happen under `dashboard` in the URL?

Example:

I link to `users/edit/1` but in the URL looks like `example.com/dashboard/users/edit/1`. Dashboard should have an index page (so `example.com/dashboard` actually shows a page) but all other URLs are appended to that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is covered pretty well in the [Larvel 4 Documentation](http://four.laravel.com/docs/routing).

Unless I'm misunderstanding, this should get you the desired results for your example case:

```
Route::get('dashboard', 'DashboardController@index');
Route::get('dashboard/users/edit/{id}', 'UsersController@edit');
etc.
```

**// edit**

Alternatively, using a Closure callback, you could do something like this:

```
Route::get('dashboard/users/{var1}/{var2?}', function($var1, $var2 = null)
{
    $controller = new UsersController;
    return $controller->{$var1}($var2);
});
```

Which wouldn't require you to specify each and every route. Or, as I mentioned below in comments, you could use a [Resource Controller](http://four.laravel.com/docs/controllers#resource-controllers) if it suits your needs.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that I could link to `dashboard/users/...`. I guess what I'm asking is if it is possible to have UsersController work off of `/dashboard/users/...` instead of `/users/...`, without having to explicitly link to `/dashboard/users/...` everywhere.

Comment: Perhaps designating it as a [Resource Controller](http://four.laravel.com/docs/controllers#resource-controllers) would work for you?

`Route::resource('dashboard/users', 'UsersController');`

Comment: Edited my answer to include an alternative solution which I think might be closer to what you're looking for.